# R script: identify the most recent file in a directory that satisfy condition

Tags: r

I want to read the most recent file with the file name : **abcd_all_XXX_9999.xlsx,** where **XXX** stands for **TET** or **KEK** or **KTET** and 9999 for cycle drummer ( 4 digits). Select period (e.g. 2015-2025) and after data manipulation (merge), the file will be saved to a new file called **CCC1_9999_y**, where y stands for a or b or c or d or e, to be chosen by me in the management of the script.
**Summarize**:

- Identify the most recent file that satisfy the condition: abcd_all_XXX_9999.xlsx, whereby abcd_all_ are fixed.
- Read a second dataset (the name of the second dataset can be anything)
- merge (one to one) the two data frames by ID.
  Save the merged dataset file called CCC1_9999_y, where y stands for a or b or c or d or e, to be chosen by me in the management of the script. 9999 correspond to the same cycle number as  abcd_all_XXX_9999.xlsx.

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Not clear for me. What means `TET`, `KEK`, `KTET`. It would also be helpful to have the structure of the input file and the desired structure of the output file using an example.

Comment: Hi @Elina Z, were you able to solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic approach to your question. Let me know if you have any issues translating this to your situation. To demo, I made three .csv files, each created a few seconds apart in my working directory `"./test"`.

We can get the names of those files with `list.files()`. In your case, you'll want to use pattern matching like this `list.files(pattern = "abcd_all_", ...)`.

Wrapping that in `file.info()`, we can retrieve metadata about each file that is detected by `list.files()`. In my example, I'm grabbing the minimum (most recent) value of `mtime` (see `?file.info()`).

Then it is straightforward to read the second dataset, merge, and write the result to file.

Note I'm using .csv files because they are easier to work with. You'll probably want to use `readxl::read_xlsx()` if you'll continue to use .xlsx.

Demo:

```
list.files(path = "./test")
#> [1] "iris.csv"  "iris2.csv" "iris3.csv"

df <- file.info(list.files(pattern = "iris", path = "./test", full.names = TRUE))
df
#>                  size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
#> ./test/iris.csv  4972 FALSE  666 2021-10-12 08:33:55 2021-10-12 08:33:17
#> ./test/iris2.csv 4972 FALSE  666 2021-10-12 08:36:43 2021-10-12 08:36:43
#> ./test/iris3.csv 4972 FALSE  666 2021-10-12 08:35:31 2021-10-12 08:35:31
#>                                atime exe
#> ./test/iris.csv  2021-10-12 08:37:15  no
#> ./test/iris2.csv 2021-10-12 08:37:15  no
#> ./test/iris3.csv 2021-10-12 08:37:15  no

newestfile <- rownames(df[df$mtime == min(df$mtime),])
newestfile
#> [1] "./test/iris.csv"

output <- merge(read.csv(newestfile), otherfile, ...)

write.csv(output, ...)
```

Your data (untested):

```
y <- "a"
vars <- c("TET", "KEK", "KTET")
years <- 2015:2025

for(v in vars){
  for(year in years){
  
    df <- file.info(list.files(
      pattern = paste0("abcd_all_", v, "_", year),
      path = ".",
      full.names = TRUE))
    
    newestfile <- rownames(df[df$mtime == min(df$mtime),])
    
    leftside <- readxl::read_xlsx(newestfile)
    
    rightside <- readxl::read_xlsx(paste0("CCC1_", year, "_", y, ".xlsx"))
    
    # all=FALSE specifies "inner-join"
    output <- merge(leftside, rightside, by = "ID", all = FALSE)
    
    write.csv(output, paste0("CC1_", year, "_", y, ".csv"))
  }
}
```